# how to have one style per angular module?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to have a CSS file per angular module so that the style files are not interfering?

What I want to do is to have bootstrap 3 in one module and bootstrap 4 in another, is this possible? If so, how to achieve it?

Comment: No,it is not possible.lets understand with example if we have three module a,b and c.if a module is use x css and then b is use y css. if we import both modules in our case a and b to c module then what happen? So module is specially design to remove redundancy of code, maintenance of the would be better.

Comment: Can your modules be active at the same time? (e.g. if module 2 is a child of module 1)

Answer (score 6):

Generally, it's not a good practice to have different files for every module. Instead, create one global CSS file and every CSS per component.

But you can create One per module as per your requirements

Create Single CSS file for every module level and import that CSS file into every component of that module's `styleUrls` array, as it accepts multiple files too. like this -

```
@Component({
  ....
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.css', 'module-global.css']
})
```

Comment: Be aware that this leads to duplication of all styles in `module-global.css` for every component it is imported into!

Comment: @daniel-sc nice catch, thanks :)

Comment: Actually because they're shared styles if you don't put them into a single global file then they're going to be duplicated anyway in their separate components css files.
You still have the same styles defined multiple times but one global file is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `module` to route then you could add the styles as `ViewEncapsulation.None` into a root component of said module. This can be used as a strategy to **lazy-load** the styles. However I seriously would like a solution that doesn't need that root component.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([{
      component: StyleWrapperComponent,
      children: routes, // rest of the routes
      pathMatch: 'prefix',
      path: ''
    }]),
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class YourModuleModule {}
```

And the component

```
@Component({
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  styleUrls: ['shared-module-styles.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class StyleWrapperComponent {}
```

Alternatively for a manual approach you could write a factory function for the `@Component` parameter to avoid declaring the the stylesheet path multiple times. You however can't lazy-load `angular.json` styles with this approach since they won't apply globally.

```
// config.ts
const moduleComponentParams = (config: Component): Component => {
  return {
    ...config,
    styleUrls: [...config.styleUrls, 'your-style-sheet.scss']
  };
};

// styled.component.ts
@Component(moduleComponentParams({
  template: `<div class="some-styles"></div>`,
}))
export class StyledComponent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of angular like angular 2 and onwards, we can have at most one angular-cli.json where we declare all the "styles" and "scripts".
Other way is that we can declare "styles" and "scripts" in index.html file which exists in "src" folder.
So, we have only two ways primarily where we can put bootstap.css and bootstrap.js in angular IO application.
So we cannot have different versions of bootstrap in different modules of angular application.
So my answer is "No".

You can define styles on per component basis but bootstrap.css requires bootstrap.js which will be only one per angular IO application.

Answer (score -3):

That is default behavior in Angular 2+, if you use angular-cli to create your components, by default it creates a .ts file, a .html file, a .css file (and spec file) for each component you create. What you put in that .css file only affects that component.

Comment: This is not what the question demands. The question was related to create a css file for one module, not for component